# asp.net config encryption reports success but actually didn't do anything

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

I'm trying to use the standard asp.net encryption to encrypt the connectionStrings section of my website. I've used this before without issue but now it reports success but has apparently done nothing.

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" .
```

I have this saved as a batch file and it exists in the same directory as the Web.config. I have ran as administrator directly from the server and I (assume) I am using the default RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.

The site is hosted in IIS under "Default Web Site" but I am using the file based (-pef) flag so presumably this shouldn't matter?

Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that it was because I was running as administrator and the working directory of course changes to c:\Windows\system32. As I am using a relative path "." I needed to add the following 2 lines to the start of my batch file:

```
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
```